# Remove parent key from json file with php

Tags: php, json, firebase, nosql

I have a php function that gets the following *json* file from a firebase DB and creates an object called `$data`.
Keep in mind that I don't know in advance the parent field: `-LYd55ZsqtoktfA58X91`

```html
{
    "-LYd55ZsqtoktfA58X91": {
        "city": "NY",
        "department": "abc0",
        "email": "awesomemail@test.com",
        "fullName": "David Awesome",
        "gender": 1,
        "hireDate": "2019-02-04",
        "isPermanent": false,
        "mobile": "123456789"
    }
}
```

**Problem**

> I need to remove the first parent field such that the output expected
>   is:

```html
 {
        "city": "NY",
        "department": "abc0",
        "email": "awesomemail@test.com",
        "fullName": "David Awesome",
        "gender": 1,
        "hireDate": "2019-02-04",
        "isPermanent": false,
        "mobile": "123456789"
   }
```

**My first approach**

knowing the parent key. I could get - for example - some property, then format this json manually. In this example I get the city value (NY).

```
echo ("City: " . $data["-LYd55ZsqtoktfA58X91"]["city"]);
```

**My second approach**

Iterating through the data, but it could be a "costly" function.

```
foreach ($data as $emp ) {
    echo implode($emp, ",");
}
```

Comment: The first one should work if you are using `json_decode($myjsonvar, TRUE)`, which will make it an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the string of json data as specified

```
$str='{
    "-LYd55ZsqtoktfA58X91": {
        "city": "NY",
        "department": "abc0",
        "email": "awesomemail@test.com",
        "fullName": "David Awesome",
        "gender": 1,
        "hireDate": "2019-02-04",
        "isPermanent": false,
        "mobile": "123456789"
    }
}';
/* decode as an array */
$json=json_decode( $str,true );
/* get the array jeys - specifically the first one */
$key=array_keys( $json )[0];
$data=json_encode( $json[ $key ] );

/* work with results */
printf("<pre>%s\n%s</pre>",$key,print_r($data,true));
```

outputs:

```
-LYd55ZsqtoktfA58X91
{"city":"NY","department":"abc0","email":"awesomemail@test.com","fullName":"David Awesome","gender":1,"hireDate":"2019-02-04","isPermanent":false,"mobile":"123456789"}
```

An alternative and more concise method would be as follows:

```
$json=json_decode( $str );
$key=array_keys( get_object_vars( $json ) )[0];

echo $json->$key->city; //NY etc
```

This second method is, in my opinion, preferable to the first method

Answer (score 0):

Given the JSON you provided (JSON with one element), I would recommend using [current()](http://php.net/current) :

```
<?php

$json = <<<JSON
{
    "-LYd55ZsqtoktfA58X91": {
        "city": "NY",
        "department": "abc0",
        "email": "awesomemail@test.com",
        "fullName": "David Awesome",
        "gender": 1,
        "hireDate": "2019-02-04",
        "isPermanent": false,
        "mobile": "123456789"
    }
}
JSON;

$data = current(json_decode($json, true));

print_r($data);
echo $data['city'];
```

https://3v4l.org/WQllZ

Given a JSON with multiple elements, if you wanted to get only the city codes, you could use [array_column()](http://php.net/array_column):

```
<?php

$json = <<<JSON
{
    "-LYd55ZsqtoktfA58X91": {
        "city": "NY",
        "department": "abc0",
        "email": "awesomemail@test.com",
        "fullName": "David Awesome",
        "gender": 1,
        "hireDate": "2019-02-04",
        "isPermanent": false,
        "mobile": "123456789"
    },
    "-LYd55ZsqtoktfA58X92": {
        "city": "CH",
        "department": "abc0",
        "email": "awesomemail@test.com",
        "fullName": "David Awesome",
        "gender": 1,
        "hireDate": "2019-02-04",
        "isPermanent": false,
        "mobile": "123456789"
    }
}
JSON;

$cities = array_column(json_decode($json, true), 'city');

print_r($cities);
```

https://3v4l.org/nkaZF